# How can i make contact group and send message to them in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to make group of some people from my contacts and then i want to send message to them. So how can i do this ?? and i dont have any idea about this so can anyone give me with deatil !!!!!

Or How can i add contact information from my app to iphone address book ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) to learn how to use the Address Book framework.